# php turn basic array into array based off of element sequence, array parsing

Tags: php, arrays

I've used simple_html_dom.php to create an array of td element values. I'd like re-organize this array into something I can work, and not just a simple list.

The array looks like this (I have shortened the amount of attributes to simplify):

```
ret[0] = 1       // player position
ret[1] = Tiger Woods  // player name
ret[3] = 68    // score
ret[4] = 2     // start of second record, player #2 position
ret[5] = Phil Mickleson // player #2 name
ret[6] = 69     // player #2 score
```

I'd like to turn this into another array:

```
$ret['position'] = 1,2
$ret['name'] = Tiger Woods, Phil Mickleson
$ret['score'] = 68, 69
```

How do I take: elements 0, 4 and place them into position
elements 1, 5 and place them into name
elements 6, 3 and place them into score

Each record contains the same amount of attributes. Please consider that my complete list of attributes is 10 not 3 as shown above.

Here is the actual code I have so far, it works and will give the array I'm working with. I would be open to any solutions that makes better use of simple_html_dom.php

```
$html = file_get_html('http://sports.yahoo.com/golf/pga/leaderboard');

// Use simple_html_dom to find all td elements as an array

$ret = $html->find('td');

// Code to remove all unwanted td elements from the array

unset($ret[0]);
unset($ret[1]);
$rem=count($ret)-1;
unset($ret[$rem]);

// Code to display all values in the array

foreach($ret as $value){
    echo $value . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: @mark covers the answer w/ array_chunk.  but you may also want to think about array_slice for getting the <td> you care about, or barmar's solution may make that unneccesary

Comment: Related: [Chunk and transpose a flat array into rows with a specific number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31740439/2943403)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate through the rows of the table, not all the TDs.

```
$ret = array('position' => array(),
             'name' => array(),
             'score' => array());
$rows = $html->find('table.sportsTable tbody tr');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cells = $row->find('td');
    $ret['position'][] = $cells[0]->plaintext;
    $ret['name'][] = $cells[1]->plaintext;
    $ret['score'][] = $cells[2]->plaintext;
}

$ret['position'] = implode(', ', $ret['position']);
$ret['name'] = implode(', ', $ret['name']);
$ret['score'] = implode(', ', $ret['score']);
```

Comment: "implode — Join array elements with a string" So in this particular case, it's taking a more complex array of arrays and concatenating into a single array by imploding with a string.

From array of arrays:

Array ( [position] => Array ( [0] => [1] => T1 [2] => T1 [3] => 3 [4] ) [name] => Array ( [0] => [1] => Martin Flores [2] => Angel Cabrera [3] => Justin Rose [4] )  [score] => Array ( [0] => [1] => 67 [2] => 66 [3] => 69 [4])

To single array:

Array ( [position] => , T1 , T1 , 3 , T4 [name] => , Martin Flores , Angel Cabrera , Justin Rose , Shawn Stefani [score] => , 67 , 66 , 69 , 69 )

Comment: No, it takes an array, and concatenates them into a string, putting the separator character between them. So `[1, 2, 3]` becomes `"1, 2, 3"`.

Comment: Ok, I see how this works now. Values of array into a string with a separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newret = array_combine (
    array('position', 'name', 'score'),
    call_user_func_array(
        'array_map',
        array_merge(array(NULL),array_chunk($ret, 3))
    )
);
var_dump($newret);
```

**EDIT**

If you want a comma separated list instead of a nested array:

```
$newret = array_map(
    function ($value) { return implode(', ', $value); },
    array_combine (
        array('position', 'name', 'score'),
        call_user_func_array(
            'array_map',
            array_merge(array(NULL),array_chunk($ret, 3))
        )
    )
);

var_dump($newret);
```

Comment: It looks like the OP wants a comma-separated list instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

Final code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php include 'simple_html_dom.php'; ?>

<?php

// Create DOM from Yahoo Sports URL
$html = file_get_html('http://sports.yahoo.com/golf/pga/leaderboard');

$ret = array('position' => array(),
             'name' => array(),
             'rd_one_score' => array());
$rows = $html->find('table.sportsTable tbody tr');

$count = 0;
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cells = $row->find('td');
    $ret['position'][] = $cells[0]->plaintext;
    $ret['name'][] = $cells[1]->plaintext;
    $ret['rd_one_score'][] = $cells[2]->plaintext;
    $count = $count+1;

}

// Build table form array

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>Position</td><td>Name</td><td>Score</td></tr>";
for ($x=1; $x<=$count; $x++) {
echo "<tr><td>",  $ret['position'][$x], "</td>";
echo "<td>",  $ret['name'][$x],  "</td>";
echo "<td>",  $ret['rd_one_score'][$x],  "</td></tr>";
} 
echo "</table>";


?>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's imagine that simple_html_dom were the library that [it should have been](http://sourceforge.net/projects/advancedhtmldom/):

```
$dom = file_get_html('http://sports.yahoo.com/golf/pga/leaderboard');
$ret = array();
$ret['position'] = implode(',', $dom->find('.sportsTable tbody tr td:eq(1)')->trim_texts);
$ret['name'] = implode(',', $dom->find('.sportsTable tbody tr td:eq(2)')->trim_texts);
$ret['score'] = implode(',', $dom->find('.sportsTable tbody tr td:eq(3)')->trim_texts);

var_dump($ret);
```