# Chunk and transpose a flat array into rows with a specific number of columns

Tags: php, arrays, grouping, transpose

An array of values are provided in the order they should appear in columns.  For example, the second value in the array should be displayed on a webpage beneath the first instead of on its right.

Task: Reorder the array so that the values are in the order they will be output in html.  The data for the first row must be first in the output.

Example inputs:

```
$input = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']; 
$cols = 2;
```

Example output:

```
[['A', 'E'], ['B','F'], ...]
```

Comment: I think you might be searching for `array_chunk` over here

Comment: Thanks it will be great help to sort this but how i get array('A','E') ,array('B','F')

Comment: array_chunk doesn't do what is needed - I put an answer on here but deleted it because it didn't do what OP requested

Comment: I didn't said that it'll answer OPs question I just said that OP might be in search of `array_chunk`

Comment: can you please help me to sort this out

Comment: Where are you getting the input data from in the first place? I can't help but feel you're asking the wrong question and the real one ought to be to get the $input in the form you want in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_chunk()` to break the array up in to `$cols`:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($array, ceil(count($array) / $cols));
```

Which would give you:

```
array(array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), array('E', 'F', 'G'));
```

Then combine the values from each array where the keys match.

```
array_unshift($chunks, null);
$chunks = call_user_func_array('array_map', $chunks);

// array(array('A', 'E'), array('B', 'F'), array('C', 'G'), array('D', NULL))
```

#### [Here's an example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/nDUzd1)

Comment: FYI: the "combine the values" two lines can be replaced with the following as of PHP 5.6.0... `$chunks = array_map(null, ...$chunks);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to count offset and then iterate over an array:

```
$input = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G');
$cols = 2;
$itemsCount = count($input);
$offset = ceil($itemsCount/$cols);

$result = array();
for($i = 0; $i < $itemsCount; ++$i) {
    if (isset($input[$i]) && isset($input[$i + $offset])) {
        $result[] = array($input[$i], $input[$i + $offset]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The modern functional equivalent of @billyonecan's approach uses the spread operator to transpose the data after it has been "chunked" to the correct size. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IFZBY))

```
$input = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']; 
$cols = 2;

var_export(
    array_map(
        null,
        ...array_chunk($input, ceil(count($input) / 2))
    )
);
// [['A', 'E'], ['B', 'F'], ['C', 'G'], ['D', null]]
```

A classic loop alternative using a modulus calculation is also attractive because it doesn't generate the extra `null` element in the final set when the division doesn't come out even: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/HuYMY))

```
$input = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']; 
$cols = 2;

$rows = ceil(count($input) / $cols);
$result = [];
foreach ($input as $i => $value) {
    $result[$i % $rows][] = $value;
}
var_export($result);
// [['A', 'E'], ['B', 'F'], ['C', 'G'], ['D']]
```

---

On this related topic, to more simply chunk and transpose with a finite number of rows, use the following: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/egLi0))

```
$rows = 2;
var_export(
    array_map(
        null,
        ...array_chunk($input, $rows)
    )
);
```