# Restructure array data by chunking, transposing, and merging

Tags: php, arrays, grouping, associative-array, transpose

I have array mentioned below, I will have value always multiple of 3.

```
$xyz = [
    ["name" => "abc"],
    ["name" => "snds"],
    ["name" => ""),
    ["number"=> "452"],
    ["number" => "845120"],
    ["number" => "84514513200"],
    ["email" => "ddddf"],
    ["email" => "dkskns"],
    ["email" => "kjnksdnkds"]
];
```

but this is not the proper format for me to perform further operations, so I want this array like mentioned below.

```
$abc = [
    [
        "name" => "abc",
        "number" => '452',
        "email" => "ddddf"
    ],
    [
        "name" => "snds",
        "number" => "845120",
        "email" => "dkskns"
    ],
    [
        "name" => "",
        "number" => "84514513200",
        "email" => "kjnksdnkds"
    ]
];
```

note: the array length is dynamic but it will always be multiple of 3

Comment: [A very near duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71963714/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility could be to use the [modulo](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) `%` operator.

In the `foreach` the value is an array and you could use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) to get the key and [reset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) to get the value of the first array element.

```
$result = [];
$count = 0;
foreach ($xyz as $value) {
    if ($count%3 === 0) {
        $count = 0;
    }
    $result[$count][array_keys($value)[0]] = reset($value);
    $count++;
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/9DDeo)

That will give you:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "abc"
    ["number"]=>
    string(3) "452"
    ["email"]=>
    string(5) "ddddf"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "snds"
    ["number"]=>
    string(6) "845120"
    ["email"]=>
    string(6) "dkskns"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["number"]=>
    string(11) "84514513200"
    ["email"]=>
    string(10) "kjnksdnkds"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
$result = array_map('array_merge', ...array_chunk($xyz, count($xyz) / 3));
```