# Click event on same button class, but invokes different action in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue. I have the code defined here:

```js
$('.js-cars-item [type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var idx = $(this).closest('li').index(); //Get the index - Number in order
  var chk = $(this).is(":checked"); //Get if checked or not
  var obj = this; //Checkbox object

  $('.js-cars-item').each(function() { //Loop every js-cars-item
    //Find the checkbox with the same index of clicked checkbox. Change disabled property
    $(this).find('li:eq(' + idx + ') [type="checkbox"]').not(obj).prop("checked", false);
  });

  var checkeds = [];
  $(".cars-item input:checkbox:checked").each(function(index) {
    checkeds[index] = $(this).attr('id');
  });
  console.clear();
  console.log("These are checked:", checkeds);
})

$('.js-add-category').click(function() {

  var categoryContent = `<div class="cars">

<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3">
      <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3">
      <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3">
      <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button type="button" class="js-add-section">Add Section</button>
</div> <br>`

  $('.main').append(categoryContent);

});


$(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-add-section', function() {
  var sectionContent = `<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-6>
      <label for="car-1-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-6>
      <label for="car-2-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-6>
      <label for="car-3-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul> </div>`

  $('.cars').append(sectionContent);

});
```

```css
.cars-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

ul {
  /* Added to fully show console in snippet */
  margin: 2px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.cars {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="js-add-category">Add Category</button> <br> <br>

<div class="main">

  <div class="cars">

    <div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3">
          <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3">
          <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3">
          <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>



    <button type="button" class="js-add-section">Add Section</button>

    <br>

    <div class="section">



    </div>



  </div>
  <br>
```

The issue is I am facing that, when I click on the `Add Section` button in a box, it adds duplicate rows in the other boxes. What I want to achieve is to add a row of checkboxes only in the box that I have clicked the 'Add Section' button.

When I click `Add Category`, it generates another box with another button `Add Section`

Please demo the code to get an overview. Please someone help me with this, I am totally stuck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$(this).parent().append(sectionContent);` instead of `$('.cars').append(sectionContent);`

Working code

```js
$('.js-cars-item [type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
  var idx = $(this).closest('li').index(); //Get the index - Number in order
  var chk = $(this).is(":checked"); //Get if checked or not
  var obj = this; //Checkbox object

  $('.js-cars-item').each(function() { //Loop every js-cars-item
    //Find the checkbox with the same index of clicked checkbox. Change disabled property
    $(this).find('li:eq(' + idx + ') [type="checkbox"]').not(obj).prop("checked", false);
  });

  var checkeds = [];
  $(".cars-item input:checkbox:checked").each(function(index) {
    checkeds[index] = $(this).attr('id');
  });
  console.clear();
  console.log("These are checked:", checkeds);
})

$('.js-add-category').click(function() {

  var categoryContent = `<div class="cars">

<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3">
      <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3">
      <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3">
      <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button type="button" class="js-add-section">Add Section</button>
</div> <br>`

  $('.main').append(categoryContent);

});

$(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-add-section', function() {
  var sectionContent = `<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-6>
      <label for="car-1-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-6>
      <label for="car-2-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-6>
      <label for="car-3-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul> </div>`

  $(this).parent().append(sectionContent);

});
```

```css
.cars-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

ul {
  /* Added to fully show console in snippet */
  margin: 2px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.cars {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="js-add-category">Add Category</button> <br> <br>

<div class="main">

  <div class="cars">

    <div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3">
          <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3">
          <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3">
          <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>



    <button type="button" class="js-add-section">Add Section</button>

    <br>

    <div class="section">



    </div>



  </div>
  <br>
```

Comment: How can I keep track of each record number of checkboxes added ?

Comment: With this `$(this).parent().children('.cars-item.js-cars-item').length` you can find number of `ul`s in each category @jones

Comment: Thanks bro. I am having another issue, please check https://jsfiddle.net/h72757cy/

I want to add the new created dynamic section to be added within `      <!-- New section to be added here -->` But, it always add after the buttons. Can you please help ?

Comment: Create a codepen please. If this answer has been answered, accept the answer and ask new one. don't append your problems to this question. @jones

Answer (score 1):

`$(".cars")` refers to *all* `.cars` elements. You only want the one that contains the button you clicked on. That would be `$(this).closest(".cars")`

To make the validation code work on newly added sections, you need to use event delegation, just like you do for the `.js-add-section` click handler.

```js
$(".main").on('change', '.js-cars-item [type="checkbox"]', function() {
  var idx = $(this).closest('li').index(); //Get the index - Number in order
  var chk = $(this).is(":checked"); //Get if checked or not
  var obj = this; //Checkbox object

  $(this).closest('.cars').find('.js-cars-item').each(function() { //Loop every js-cars-item
    //Find the checkbox with the same index of clicked checkbox. Change disabled property
    $(this).find('li:eq(' + idx + ') [type="checkbox"]').not(obj).prop("checked", false);
  });

  var checkeds = [];
  $(this).closest(".cars").find(".cars-item input:checkbox:checked").each(function(index) {
    checkeds[index] = $(this).attr('id');
  });
  console.clear();
  console.log("These are checked:", checkeds);
})

$('.js-add-category').click(function() {

  var categoryContent = `<div class="cars">

<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3">
      <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3">
      <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3">
      <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button type="button" class="js-add-section">Add Section</button>
</div> <br>`

  $('.main').append(categoryContent);

});


$(document.body).on('click', 'button.js-add-section', function() {
  var sectionContent = `<div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-6>
      <label for="car-1-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-6>
      <label for="car-2-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
      <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-6>
      <label for="car-3-6"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
    </li>
  </ul> </div>`

  $(this).closest('.cars').append(sectionContent);

});
```

```css
.cars-item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

ul {
  /* Added to fully show console in snippet */
  margin: 2px;
}

li {
  display: inline;
}

.cars {
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 250px;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="js-add-category">Add Category</button> <br> <br>

<div class="main">

  <div class="cars">

    <div class="cars-item js-cars-item">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-1-3">
          <label for="car-1-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-2-3">
          <label for="car-2-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" id="car-3-3">
          <label for="car-3-3"><i class="icon-tick"></i></label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="js-add-section">Add Section</button>

    <br>

    <div class="section">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
```

Comment: Hi @Barmar, can you solve this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424385/change-php-array-format

Comment: Thank you bro. Also, how can I apply my validation check after each added row of checkboxes ? Meaning if I have added two sections, and I click the first checkbox in the second row, and I click the first checkbox in the third row, it should not be checked.

The first row of checkboxes will always be checked and is independent.

Comment: `$(this).closest(".js-cars-items")`

Comment: Where do I replace this ?

Comment: Instead of `$('.js-cars-item')`. It's the same idea as the solution to the original problem. If you want to stay in the same DIV, use `$(this).closest()` to find the relevant container.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the problem. None of the new checkboxes run the validation code because you didn't use event delegation for that.

Comment: The add section is working correctly. Just that I want to add validation as from the second of checkboxes and onwards if I add additional rows of checkboxes. I want to start the validation as from Row 2. Please help. The last issue.

Comment: Maybe this, instead of the `.each()` loop: `$(this).closest(".js-cars-items").find('li:eq(' + idx + ') [type="checkbox"]').not(obj).prop("checked", false);`

Comment: @Barmar : Nope. it still allow the checkboxes to be checked. 

See : https://jsfiddle.net/fL3hekhw/4/

Comment: Validation should occur as from rows after the `Add Section` button

Comment: The comment says you want to change the `disabled` property, but you're changing the `checked` property.

Comment: You need to delegate with `$(".cars").on("change", '.js-cars-item [type="checkbox"]', function...)`

Comment: Either the above is checked or the bottom is checked. I tried with `$(".cars").on("change", '.js-cars-item [type="checkbox"]', function...)` no results either :(

Comment: @Barmar : Please help :(

Comment: If you want mutually exclusive checkboxes, why don't you use radio buttons?

Comment: @Barmar : The requirement is such. Thank you very much Barmar. You have been very helpful.